# Positive random number generation with given mean and standard deviation

Tags: random, mean, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I am working on a simulation project. Need help on random number generation. I need two sets of random numbers.

Properties:

1. Primary set (var_a) > Normally distributed, greater than 0, with given mean and std.
2. Secondary set (var_b) -> Same as a primary set, with an addition, that second set cannot be greater than primary set. The reason being the output of a deterministic function will be in percentage between 0-1 only. For example:

[service level calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zzrh.png)

```
import numpy as np

n = 100000

# Calls Handled
callshandled = np.random.normal(loc=65,  scale=97, size=n)
print('Calls handled: ', callshandled)

# Call handled within sl. Has to always be less or equal to Calls Handled
ansinsl = np.random.normal(loc=60,  scale=82, size=n)
print('Answered in SL', ansinsl)

# Service Level - Has to be between 0-1. With normal distribution we get values in negative
sl = np.array(ansinsl)/np.array(callshandled)
print('Service level', sl)

Calls handled:  [ 43.26825426 129.79198758  31.56460354 ...  37.45059791   1.71420416
 -94.87241356]
Answered in SL [-12.72293091 204.28084996 232.25722235 ... 166.03208722 -53.69933624
 -36.71949656]
Service level [ -0.29404771   1.57390956   7.35815427 ...   4.43336279 -31.32610312
   0.38704082]
```

Comment: Sorry missed adding a simple calculation: it service_level = b/a

Comment: What language are you using? Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: It's python. Added sample code

Comment: If you are using Python, the statistics & random library in Scipy has an out-of-the-box [truncated normal distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html), that would save you part of the rejections. For a right bound b that is infinite, you can use `b = numpy.inf`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a well-known “natural” way of generating *pairs* of Gaussian pseudo-random variates, known as [Box-Muller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform).

You could try it that way:

1. generate pairs of unit normal variates à la Box-Muller
2. scale the pairs to whatever your (µ,σ) parameters are
3. reject the pairs that do not fit your criteria

Comment: Thanks, will try this. Posted sample code for more clarity.